# AttributeError when trying to use Colorama (not a good title, I know)

Tags: python, python-3.x, colorama

I don't even know what to title this, as I don't know the terms. Basically, I have what I assume to be a beginner question, which I can't find an answer for. So, here's my code:

```
from colorama import Fore, Back, Style, init
init()
def colorprint(str1, str2):
    print(Fore.str2 + str1 + Fore.WHITE)
colorprint("words", "GREEN")
```

But, as expected, I can't use "str2" in "Fore.", as it's not one of the "options" (I guess) for it...

I get this error:
`AttributeError: 'AnsiFore' object has no attribute 'str2'`

Sorry for not knowing how to label stuff... I don't know whether to call things functions, variables, objects, etc.

I'm using Python 3.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `Fore` object doesn't have the `str2` attribute, but you can use the [`getattr` function](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#getattr) to get `Fore.{GREEN}`:

```
from colorama import Fore, Back, Style, init
init()
def colorprint(str1, str2):
    print(getattr(Fore, str2) + str1 + Fore.WHITE)
colorprint("words", "GREEN")
```